# Sort value that are from a JSON file with str.split

Tags: python, json

i have a JSON file with book information.
In the original file there are more.

Example:

```
     [{"author": "Wes McKinney", "price": 53, "title": "Python for Data     Analysis", "publication_year": "2012", "topic": "programming"}, 
      {"author": "Joel Grus", "price": 66, "title": "Data Science from Scratch", "publication_year": "2015", "topic": "Python"}]
```

Now i would like to sort the information based on the last name of the author.
I did the following:

```
names = []
for a in jsondata:
names.append(str.split((a['author'])))

print (sorted(names))
```

Then i get information like this:

```
[['Allan', 'Downey'], ['Allan', 'Downey']
```

I was wondering if someone could give me a hint/tip what to use how i can sort all the information based on the last name of the author.

Answer (score 1):

You may sort your JSON structure using `sorted()` with `lambda` expression as:

```
lambda x: x["author"].split()[-1]
# split value of "author", key and sort based on the last word
```

There is no need to explicitly iterate over the list, and create another list to maintain the names.

Sample run:

```
>>> my_json = [
        {"author": "Wes McKinney", "price": 53, "title": "Python for Data     Analysis", "publication_year": "2012", "topic": "programming"},
        {"author": "Joel Grus", "price": 66, "title": "Data Science from Scratch", "publication_year": "2015", "topic": "Python"}
    ]

>>> sorted(my_json, key=lambda x: x["author"].split()[-1])
[{'topic': 'Python', 'price': 66, 'title': 'Data Science from Scratch', 'publication_year': '2015', 'author': 'Joel Grus'}, {'topic': 'programming', 'price': 53, 'title': 'Python for Data     Analysis', 'publication_year': '2012', 'author': 'Wes McKinney'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
names = []
for a in jsondata:
    last_name = a["author"].split(" ")[1]
    names.append(last_name)

print(sorted(names))
```

If you would like to get sorted dictionaries, you can do it like this:

```
for a in sorted(jsondata, key=lambda x: x["author"].split(" ")[1]):
    # You can use dict any way you like. E.g.:
    print(a["title"] + " " + str(a["price"]))
```

Comment: Do or do not. There is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to sort the `jsondata` list with an appropriate key function that extracts the last name from the value associated with each dict's "author" key.

I've used the `.rsplit` method so we can efficiently handle suthors who have more than 2 names. `.rsplit(None, 1)` splits the string on whitespace from the right, making (at most) one split, returning a list containing (at most) two elements. The last name will be the the last element of that list. If you want the last name of "Guido Van Rossum" to be "Van Rossum" then you'll need to use a different splitting strategy.

```
import json

jsondata = [
    {
        "author": "Wes McKinney", "price": 53, 
        "title": "Python for Data     Analysis", 
        "publication_year": "2012", "topic": "programming"
    },
    {
        "author": "Joel Grus", "price": 66, 
        "title": "Data Science from Scratch", 
        "publication_year": "2015", "topic": "Python"
    },
    {
        "author": "One",
    },
    {
        "author": "Person With A Long Name",
    },
]

def last_name(d):
    return d["author"].rsplit(None, 1)[-1]

# Verify that `last_name` does what we want
for d in jsondata:
    print(last_name(d))

jsondata.sort(key=last_name)

print(json.dumps(jsondata, indent=4))
```

**output**

```
McKinney
Grus
One
Name
[
    {
        "title": "Data Science from Scratch",
        "author": "Joel Grus",
        "topic": "Python",
        "publication_year": "2015",
        "price": 66
    },
    {
        "title": "Python for Data     Analysis",
        "author": "Wes McKinney",
        "topic": "programming",
        "publication_year": "2012",
        "price": 53
    },
    {
        "author": "Person With A Long Name"
    },
    {
        "author": "One"
    }
]
```